# How to create a "cache" or "bucket" for streams?

Tags: node.js

There are times I would need to download a file (say a streaming video) and then wait for information (namely the file size) about this video to return before I can call for an upload sdk to pass the download steam to it. The problem is I would often encounter the `Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end` error because it is possible the stream has already ended.

```
(async () => {
  const video = http('https://www.google.com/m3u8.mp4');
  const filesize = await getFileSize('https://www.google.com/m3u8.mp4');
  uploadToCOS(video.pipe, filesize);
})();
```

In this case I would need a "cache" or "bucket" for the said stream before I pass it to he uploader. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It appears that you need to show more detail here such as what the functions `http()`, `getFileSize()` and `uploadToCOS()` do as none of those are standard functions we would know.  Can you point to documentation or code for those?

Comment: they are all made-up async functions

Comment: It's kind of hard for us to help you solve problems in made-up code.  You say you're encountering the error `Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end`.  You must be running some real code to generate an error.  From your rep, it appears you've been around here long enough to know that questions about code need to include the relevant code - without that, we're trying to make blind guesses how to help.  With no idea what those functions do or even where the error comes from, it seems unlikely anyone here can help you.

Comment: If you're getting that error from real code, show us that real code.